# C: Function to generate random string and add it to struct

Tags: c, struct

Coming from some experience with Java/C#, I'm struggling to get my head around some parts of C. I have an array of structs. These structs, at the moment, have only one member (I'll be adding others down the track) - an array of chars. This array is a string of 6 characters - two letters, four digits (e.g. XY1234).

The follow code produces the objectCode I'm looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET 26

typedef struct object {
    char objectCode[6];
} object_t;

void GetRandomSeed() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}

char RandomLetter() {
    return 'A' + rand() % LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET;
}

int RandomDigit() {
    return rand() % 10;
}

int main() {

    GetRandomSeed();

    object_t object1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        object1.objectCode[i] = RandomLetter();
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        object1.objectCode[i] = '0' + RandomDigit();
    }

    // Print objectCode string to screen
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            printf("%c", object1.objectCode[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to wrap the for loops (the ones randomly generating the code) in a function. However, the print out of my attempt to do this is just gibberish:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET 26

typedef struct object {
    char objectCode[6];
} object_t;


void GetRandomSeed() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}

char RandomLetter() {
    return 'A' + rand() % LETTERS_IN_ALPHABET;
}

int RandomDigit() {
    return rand() % 10;
}

void GenerateCode(object_t object) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        object.objectCode[i] = RandomLetter();
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        object.objectCode[i] = '0' + RandomDigit();
    }
}

int main() {

    GetRandomSeed();

    object_t object1;

    // Print objectCode string to screen
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            printf("%c", object1.objectCode[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

I'm bit of an infant when it comes to C so I really appreciate any help you can give. Thanks.

Comment: you forgot to call GenerateCode() in your main routine : you're printing the uninitialized char array values (usually 0xCDCDCDCD or 0xFFFFFF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the call to `GenerateCode` on `main`, that's the reason the print output is *gibberish*.

However another issue is that on the `GenerateCode` function, the parameter is by value and the function won't modify the original struct on main. In C, all and every parameters are by value. You should pass a pointer to the struct:

```
void GenerateCode(object_t* object) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        object->objectCode[i] = RandomLetter();
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        object->objectCode[i] = '0' + RandomDigit();
    }
}

int main() {

    // ...
    object_t object1;

    GenerateCode(&object1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you pass in an object by value to `GenerateCode()` the function modifies only the value on the stack (ie: the parameter itself), not the actual object you want to change. use a pointer:

```
void GenerateCode(object_t* object) {
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    object->objectCode[i] = RandomLetter();
}

for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
    object->objectCode[i] = '0' + RandomDigit();
}
}
```

and call it like:

```
GenerateCode(&object1);
```